# Surface Book 2 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, surface

This question has probably been asked a lot regarding compatibility, which I have already discovered and understand. My question is more on the warranty of the device after I have put Ubuntu on it. I live in Australia which has fairly strict consumer rights laws, and I read somewhere that as long as the factory windows image is still on the device all is well. However, I looked at my own warranty booklet and it states that if the hardware is used with another operating system other than the pre-installed version of windows then my warranty is void. I wish to keep my warranty intact just in case but I also need to dual boot with Ubuntu or any other Linux os as I am studying software engineering.

I have also tried running a virtual machine both with hyper-v and vmware and virtual box but that has given me nothing but headaches and compatibility issues. It also drains my batteries like crazy.

My last resort would be to get a cheap laptop or build a desktop as a dedicated Linux or hackintosh device. But that costs money and I definitely do not have enough for that at this time.

If anyone else has any other suggestions please let me know!

Thanks for all your help!